# how can I get raw html for a web page using javascript automator (JAX) for mac yosemite?

Tags: javascript, applescript, osx-yosemite, automator, javascript-automation

I figured out how to open a web page, but I want to submit a form to google and then get the html results.  how can I do this? I want to take those page results so I can parse the data myself.

```
chrome = Application("Google Chrome");
win = chrome.Window().make();
chrome.windows[0].tabs[0].url = "https://google.com";
// submit form button to search for "test"
//generated_html_from_chrome = ??
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are genuinely wanting just the raw html of google searches, then no need to use Chrome at all; just use the command line to get the text directly, using something like curl.

```
var mysearch = "test"
app = Application.currentApplication()
app.includeStandardAdditions = true
app.doShellScript('curl -D - https://www.google.com/#q=' + mysearch)
```

If you do need to be working in Chrome, we can figure that out too. Just say so.